# Turn character into number and arrange the number in c

Tags: c

```
int T, i;
scanf("%d", &T);

char a[T], b[T], c[T];
int temp[T], temp2[T], temp3[T];
int point1[T], point2[T], point3[T];
for(i=0;i<T; i++){
    scanf("%c %c %c", &a[i], &b[i], &c[i]);
    switch(a[i]){
        case '!':
            point1[i] = 5;
            break;
        case '%':
            point1[i] = 4;
            break;
        case '&':
            point1[i] = 3;
            break;
        case '^':
            point1[i] = 2;
            break;
        case '|':
            point1[i] = 1;
            break;
        default :
            point1[i]=10;
    }
    switch(b[i]){
        case '!':
            point2[i] = 5;
            break;
        case '%':
            point2[i] = 4;
            break;
        case '&':
            point2[i] = 3;
            break;
        case '^':
            point2[i] =2;
            break;
        case '|':
            point2[i] =1;
            break;
        default :
        point2[i]=10;
    }
    switch(c[i]){
        case '!':
            point3[i] = 5;
            break;
        case '%':
            point3[i] = 4;
            break;
        case '&':
            point3[i] = 3;
            break;
        case '^':
            point3[i] =2;
            break;
        case '|':
            point3[i] =1;
            break;
        default :
        point3[i]=10;   
    }

    if(point1[i]<point2[i]) {
            temp[i]=point1[i];
            point1[i]=point2[i];
            point2[i]=temp[i];
    }

    if(point1[i]<point3[i]){
            temp2[i]=point1[i];
            point1[i]=point3[i];
            point3[i]=temp2[i];
    }

    if(point2[i]<point3[i]){
            temp3[i]=point2[i];
            point2[i]=point3[i];
            point3[i]=temp3[i];
    }

    printf("%d %d %d\n", point1[i], point2[i], point3[i]);
}

return 0;
```

So first of all, i was asked to input certain characters randomly arranged and make them printed arranged from the highest precedence.

The precedence of the operators (from the highest to the lowest) are "!" (logical NOT), "%" (remainder), "&"
(bitwise AND), "^" (bitwise XOR), , "|" (bitwise OR).

So i try to change the characters into numbers and try to arrange the number first then change the number again to the characters.

But when i try to check if the numbers have been correctly arranged, it's not.

Any idea what's wrong with my code?
Or any idea to make my code simpler without having to turn the characters into numbers?

Here's the sample

Sample Input

```
3
& ^ %
& ^ !
& ^ !
```

Sampe Output

```
Case #1: % & ^
Case #2: ! & ^
Case #3: ! & ^
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &T);` leaves ENTER in the input buffer for the next `"%c"`. Best way to deal with user input is to avoid `scanf()` and use `fgets()` (possibly followed by `sscanf()`).

Comment: Character IS number in C. So I can't understand what you are trying to change and convert...

Comment: You would save yourself a lot of typing and nerve if you wrote a function for enumerating your characters and called it three times. Also, there is a standard function for sorting called `qsort`; there is no need to sort your characters yoursefl.

Comment: I'll also recommend `fgets` instead of `scanf` but you could try this: `scanf("%c %c %c", &a[i], &b[i], &c[i]);` ==> `scanf(" %c %c %c", &a[i], &b[i], &c[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

A few issues have already been noted in the comments. Specifically, `scanf` leaves the trailing newline in the input buffer. You can fix that using the suggestion by @4386427.

You can avoid manually assigning numbers for each character by noting that their ASCII is already in required order. That is, '!' < '%' < '&' < '^' < '|'. So you can simply read them into a char array of the appropriate size and just sort them in ascending order before printing the char array. This will significantly shorten and clean up your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return (*((char*)a) > *((char*)b)) - (*((char*)a) < *((char*)b));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int T, i, j;
    scanf(" %d", &T);

    /* TODO: Check if number of chars per line is T or 3. */
    char *a = malloc(T * sizeof(char));        
    for(i = 0; i < T; i++) {            
        for (j = 0; j < T; j++) {
            scanf(" %c", &a[j]);
        }

        printf("Before sort\n");
        for (j = 0; j < T; j++) {
            printf("%c ", a[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        qsort(a, T, sizeof(a[0]), cmpfunc);

        printf("After sort\n");
        for (j = 0; j < T; j++) {
            printf("%c ", a[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(a);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `cmpfunc` is subject to overflow, better as `return (*((char*)a) > *((char*)b)) - (*((char*)a) < *((char*)b));` which eliminate the possibility by returning the difference of the results of the conditional expressions. (e.g. `1-1` or `1-0` or `0-1`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Fixed. Thanks for spotting the mistake.

Comment: Much better. There are a number of those little tid-bits that can help save you from yourself at times `:)`